# Print page numbers inside HTML <tfoot> when printing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to print bill type HTML page.
Due to the length of the Bill there may be multiple pages.
Following is the structure of the HTML page

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>
      <div class="header">...</div>
    </td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>
      <div class="content">...</div>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

`<thead>` and `<tfoot>` will be available on each page.
What I need is print the page number on each page when printing.
When I use `counter-increment` it always showing No 1

Answer (score -1):

Try `counter-increment: page;` `content: counter(page);`.

```css
.footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

.footer:after {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: counter(page);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="header">...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="content">...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="footer">...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked if I put the counter to zero before incrementing it, if not the counter always showed the number 1.

```
body {
    /* Set "my-sec-counter" to 0 */
    counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
}

.footer::after {
    /* Increment "my-sec-counter" by 1 */
    counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
    content: "Counter " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach also. But not working for <tfoot>

Comment: Not working changing the ".footer::after" for "tfoot::after"?

Comment: Unfortunately. that also doesn't work. Always counter is 1